# Bash STDERR still appearing after redirection

Tags: bash, yum, io-redirection

I am trying to parse the output of `yum check-update` in Bash 4 (Red Hat) and want to skip the first line that states:

*'This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.'*

I used strace to determine the FD and it appears to be 2/STDERR but redirecting it with `2>/dev/null` does not work.  What could be the cause?

Strace output:

```
write(2, "This system is not registered to"..., 112This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
) = 112
```

Comment: You should be able to delete your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I am so sorry, I just woke up.  I was piping the output through grep and had my redirection on the wrong side of the pipe!  I was redirecting the stderr of grep not yum!  Mods, feel free to delete this, or leave it up if it has any value.

Comment: This would be fine to keep, but let this be an example why you should post the full command you're running. Your question shows nothing about using `grep` and there would have been no way to determine this was the issue.